# What does "the main entrance is around the back of the building" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ok, I found this sentence "**The real entrance is actually around the back of the house, on the ground floor**" in [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4145030/Retired-builder-65-knocks-bizarre-UPSIDE-house.html)

let look at this picture
[image]

This building has 4 sides

-The orange one is the front of the building

-The green one is the back of the building

-The purple one is **one** side of the building. The other side of the building is not colored.

So, What does it mean when we say "**the main entrance is around the back of the building**"?

**Does it mean the main entrance is at the green or purple one?**

***Note***: **The orange side faces the main street**

Also, in the dictionary

> [Around](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/around#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_around_2) (preposition) d : on or to another side of (something)
>
> We were surprised by what we saw when we walked around the corner.
>
> There's another door around the back of the house.

if this meaning applies to the word "**around**", it means the main entrance is not at the back of the house but on one of the sides of the house

Comment: Where is the street? In front of the orange side?

Comment: @KarlG, yes, the orange side faces the main street

Comment: Hi Tom, I noticed that you've posted essentially the same question 3 times ([once on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/155986/24861)). Just wondering: are they actually different questions?

Answer (score 1):

Literally, it means the green side. However, this description is considered fairly vague, so if someone said this to me I'd probably ask for more specific directions as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how carefully somebody is speaking, which we can't tell without knowing them, knowing the circumstances, knowing their relation to the hearer, etc.

Narrowly construed, it means the green side. But more loosely, they may mean anywhere that isn't the orange.

Comment: In particular, if the entrance was on the purple side, a at the end nearest the green, this could be clearer than saying "round the side" - even more so if there's a fire exit just round the corner. Also buildings are rarely simple rectangles